# Recursive implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

Imagine the following code:

```
trait Converter[T] {
  def convert(value: String): T
}

object Converter {
  implicit val intConverter: Converter[Int] = value => value.toInt
  implicit def optionConverter[T]: Converter[Option[T]] = new OptionConverter[T]
}

class OptionConverter[T](implicit val ev: Converter[T]) extends Converter[Option[T]] {
  ...
}
```

As you can see the `OptionConverter` takes in a `Converter[T]` for the type its containing but the compiler complains because when it tries to compile `OptionConverter` it doesn't know the type.

I imagine this probably has already been solved...but I can't figure a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just accept the wrapped `Converter` as an implicit param to the `optionConverter` method:

```
implicit def optionConverter[T](implicit ev: Converter[T]): Converter[Option[T]] = new OptionConverter[T]
```

Or the shorthand:

```
implicit def optionConverter[T : Converter]: Converter[Option[T]] = new OptionConverter[T]
```